# Graphics.DrawString chopping mid-word

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, user-controls, gdi+

I have created a usercontrol which is basically a button with some nice little features.

One of those features is that it determines the largest font size possible for the text, whilst keeping the text within the confines on the box.

This works fine in the majority of cases, but sometimes it will chop a word in half to fit it in.

So it might appear as..

```
stackov 
erflow
```

Rather than

```
stackoverflow
```

(but in a smaller font)

I thought that there would have been a StringFormatFlag to allow me to specify how word-wrapping is done.

I want word wrapping, but not 'character' wrapping.

Thanks
Rich.

Comment: Can you post your text drawing code?

Comment: the code wasn't complicated, but your suggested answer solved my problems.. thanks again !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using TextRenderer instead:

```
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
                        "stackoverflow",
                        this.Font,
                        new Rectangle(10, 10, 32, 32),
                        Color.Black,
                        Color.Empty,
                        TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter);

  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
                        "stack overflow",
                        this.Font,
                        new Rectangle(50, 10, 32, 32),
                        Color.Black,
                        Color.Empty,
                        TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter);
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic.. I've been working with .net graphics for ages, and never come across this **TextRenderer** class. It seems to be doing the trick.. thanks a lot !! :-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify [StringFormatFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformatflags.aspx).NoWrap when populating the [StringFormat.FormatFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.formatflags.aspx) property.  Then use one of the DrawString overloads that accepts a StringFormat class.  One of the following three methods:

[DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142058.aspx)(String, Font, Brush, PointF, StringFormat)

[DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs.aspx)(String, Font, Brush, RectangleF, StringFormat)

[DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3thd43b.aspx)(String, Font, Brush, Single, Single, StringFormat)

Comment: Hi, I understand that, and I'm using the StringFormatFlags, but it is wrapping mid-word, which is my problem.